# org.apache.tika.utils.XMLReaderUtils acquireSAXParser WARNING: Contention waiting for a SAXParser. Consider increasing the XMLReaderUtils.POOL_SIZE

Tags: nutch, apache-tika, tika-server, nutch2

when running nutch jobs it is showing as

> Oct 13, 2020 8:46:18 AM org.apache.tika.utils.XMLReaderUtils
> acquireSAXParser WARNING: Contention waiting for a SAXParser. Consider
> increasing the XMLReaderUtils.POOL_SIZE
> May I know what it means.I using num threads as 150 and numfetchers are 3.Should I need to change this parameters.Let me know.

Comment: What code are you using to call Apache Tika? Without that code, it's hard to tell you how to increase the pool size...

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2582, it's an open issue to make Nutch adjust Tika's XMLReaderUtils.POOL_SIZE. Given a default pool size of 10 this warning can be ignored if there are not significantly more than 10 CPU cores available, even if the number of parsing fetcher threads is larger. It doesn't matter whether threads are waiting for a SAXParser or later for CPU resources when parsing.